# Firebase data structure for performance vs querying

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm debating on data structures. I have a list of items that can either be `public` or `per-user`. Here are my 2 options

```
//1
items: 
   item1 { authorId: "system"  }
    item2 { authorId: "user1"  }

//2
items: 
    system
          item1 {   }
    user1
          item2 {  }
//3
items: 
   item1 { }
   item2 { }

user-items: 
   system { items: {item1: true} }
   user1 {  items: {item2: true}  }
```

**Structure 1**:

- harder to query
- I don't need to know the type of an item to query it (all i need is id)

**Structure 2**:

- Easier to query
- Possibly better performance
- I need to know whether an item is public or per user to be able to query it

**Structure 3**:

- More flexible
- Requires multiple queries to fetch expected data (fetch user-items, fetch item ids, and then for each id fetch the item)

Any recommendations?

Comment: For this to be answerable, you'd need to list the ways in which you need to be able query the data, as that's the starting point for choosing any particular database structure.

Comment: I need to query either public or per-user data